# Complex ListView example with complex data and complex layout of each row?

Tags: android, listview, layout

Im pulling a list of product objects from a database call and I want to build a ListView of the data in my activity with a non-scrolling header and footer. Each row will consist of a product thumbnail, some data and a button arranged horizontally. I understand that using the ListView I can inflate each row using a separate layout.

Most of the examples Ive seen using ListView just show a simple array of strings that fill the whole view of the activity, but most real-world examples will be more complex and I can't find any good examples that explain how all these pieces fit together.

Does anyone have any pointers to sample code with a good explanation ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An example that helped me a lot:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

I hope this would be useful to you too.

Comment: the first link is dead can you supply a substitute? Thanks.

Comment: The first link is dead and the second link just talk about layouting without explaining how to populate the layout

Answer (score 5):

```
private static class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    protected ListView mListView;

    protected static class RowViewHolder {
        public TextView mTitle;
        public TextView mText;
    }

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Activity activity) {
        super();
        mListView = activity.getListView();
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // do what you need to do
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.row_layout, null);

        RowViewHolder holder = new RowViewHolder();
        holder.mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Title);
        holder.mText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Text);

        holder.mTitle.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener);
        holder.mText.setOnClickListener(mOnTextClickListener);

        view.setTag(holder);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to have a complex row in a ListView is via a SimpleAdapter.  There are a number of examples around for that.

To force the ListView to fill the remaining portion of the screen, set the properties as follows:

Use a LinearLayout.

On the list view:

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent",
android:height="0dp",
android:layout_weight="1"
```

On all other widgets:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Do not set a height or layout_weight

Comment: Another example that doesn't show the main layout XML either. Normally an application will have a header, a list of items and maybe some more widgets near the bottom. Not sure how to have the bottom widgets stay at the bottom and not take over the whole parent. I want the list view to expand to fill the space between the header and footer widgets but after that it should just scroll without affecting the them.